# Android Seekbar with max progress != max value

Tags: android, seekbar

I'd like to set a max progress value in a Seekbar that is not the same as the max value.

For example max would be 100 and max progress 50, so the progress slider could only be dragged to the middle. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: perhaps divide max_value by 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

```
int seekBarMaxValue = 100;
int seekBarDraggableMaxValue = 50;

seekBar.setMax(seekBarMaxValue );

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangetListener() {
  public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
     seekBar.setProgress(progress > seekBarDraggableMaxValue ? seekBarDraggableMaxValue : progress);
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, i was busy with other stuff... This seems a bit hacky, but i guess it's the only working solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want three numbers only (ex. 0; 50; 100); just pretend each number is represents another number or multiply the progress by the common divisor:

Example

- 0 = 0 or (0 * 50)
- 1 = 50 or (1 * 50)
- 2 = 100 or (2 * 50)

  ```
  int int_actual_number = 0;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  seek_sample.setMax(2);
  seek_sample.setProgress(0);
  seek_sample.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
          int_actual_number = progress * 50;

      }

      @Override
      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }

  });
  ```

You can use different common divisors and amount of numbers to test this method for your needs.